# How to declare a variable as list of string array in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I am currently using angular 2.0 and in typescript file I want to declare a variable which is a list of string array. I am doing something like this yAxis_val: list which is not working.

Please let me know the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define a string array as follows:

```
public yAxis_val: string[][];
```

To initialize you would do:

```
public yAxis_val: string[][] = [];
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no List data structure in [typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html). You would use arrays.

```
private yAxisVal: string[][]
```

Comment: If my back end code in C# is returning me a list of string array, and in typescript I have declared a variable as private yAxisVal: string[][], then will I be able to map list of string array object from back end code to the typescript model object yAxisVal.

Answer (score 0):

```
you can define like below let me know if any query or questions

import { Component, inject } from '@angular/core';
import { BreakpointObserver, Breakpoints } from '@angular/cdk/layout';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map, shareReplay } from 'rxjs`enter code here`/operators';
import { AsyncPipe, NgIf } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-nav',
  templateUrl: './nav.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./nav.component.css']
})
export class NavComponent {
  menuItems:string[];
  private breakpointObserver = inject(BreakpointObserver);

  isHandset$: Observable<boolean> = this.breakpointObserver.observe(Breakpoints.Handset)
    .pipe(
      map(result => result.matches),
      shareReplay()
    );

    constructor(){
     this.menuItems = ['dashboard', 'sales', 'orders', 'customers', 'products'];
    }
}
```